# Restore HAProxy stats

Tags: haproxy

I use following command to restart HAProxy, when changing the configurration file:

```
/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(</var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

Sadly after the HAProxy is back all stats of the previous launch are away.

Is there a possibility in HAProxy to restore stats from a previous HAProxy start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done unfortunately. HAProxy's stats are all in memory, so when restarting (even gracefully with -sf), those stats get lost.

Comment: I guess there is really no possibility to do this so i will close this question.

Answer (score 7):

As of version 1.6, you can dump server states into a flat file right before performing the reload and let the new process know where the states are stored. 
See example here:[seamless_reload](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/ebec7ecb157c79a9da9283ff38636e4e0ee1fac3/examples/seamless_reload.txt.)

The "show servers state" command is used to keep servers uptime and healthy status cross reload, but it doesn't give session data, or bytes in/out, etc. "show stat" command can dump these stats to a file that you can use to create a report later, although HAproxy doesn't have a feature to reload this information.

Answer (score 0):

Might you can export data to CSV file before doing reload/restart

```
"http://localhost:8080/haproxy?stats;csv"
```

or

```
curl -u <USER>:<MyPASSWORD> "http://localhost:8080/haproxy?stats;csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

according to HAproxy 1.5 [doc](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt) you can clear all stats using the unix socket.

> clear counters all
>
> Clear all statistics counters in each proxy (frontend & backend) and in each
> server. This has the same effect as restarting. This command is restricted
> and can only be issued on sockets configured for level "admin".